# Electron BrowserWindow switches to Dark Mode when opening DevTools

Tags: html, css, electron, google-chrome-devtools, darkmode

## Dark Mode Confusion with DevTools

I'm building an basic electron app from a tutorial.

I have a BrowserWindow launching with some basic HTML and CSS Styling - Just the word "Awesome" in blue with a white background. However, my Windows and most apps that allow me to (Chrome, VS Code, etc.) are all set to dark mode.

When I launch the app, it comes up with a white background, but as soon as I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open the Dev Tools, the WebView converts to Dark Mode, both for the Dev Tools, and for the output screen.

Original View:

- [image]

After opening DevTools:

- [image]

Even weirder - if I close DevTools, it goes back to a white background, then if I open DevTools again, it **STAYS** with the original white background in the main window view (Although DevTools itself appears to be in Dark Mode).

- [image]

### Question:

How do I prevent the Dev Tools from switching modes when opened - at least on the main display for my Electron App?

---

### The code for the webview of the Electron BrowserWindow

#### `countdown.html`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./countdown.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Awesome!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `countdown.css`:

```css
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Open the `Rendering` panel in devtools and see if you have color emulation set.

Comment: @wOxxOm All the emulation settings (the last 4 options) are set to "no emulation".

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution, but one option is to explicitly set the `backgroundColor` option at window creation:

```js
app.on('ready', _ => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#FFF', // Add this new line
        height: 400,
        width: 900
    })
```

This code will set the background color to white and the shift to dark mode doesn't happen when DevTools is opened the first time (or any time).

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack, but...
If you toggle developer tools open/closed/open, it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

We can modify this behavior by tweaking the settings of DevTools, for this go to Developer Tools -> Settings (clicking the little cog wheel on top right of DevTools), then Preferences -> Appearance, choose 'light' from the dropdown.

The Browser Window should be restarted by re-running the process.